# Can anyone tell me how I can improve gas requirement?

Tags: contract-design, ether, remix, gas, gas-limit

Below is my smart contract. Remix gives warnings on each of the following functions:

```
Gas requirement of function MedicalRecord.addNote(bytes32,bytes32) high: infinite.
Gas requirement of function Voting.allCandidates() high: infinite.
Gas requirement of function  Voting.indexOfCandidate(bytes32)  high: infinite.
Gas requirement of function Voting.transferBalance()  high: infinite.
Gas requirement of function Voting.voteForCandidate(bytes32,uint256) high: infinite.
```

Here is smart contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Voting {
  bytes32[] public candidateList;
  uint public totalTokens;
  uint public balanceTokens;
  uint public tokenPrice;

  address public owner;

  struct voter {
    address voterAddress;
     uint tokensBought;
     uint[] tokensUsedPerCandidate;
  }

  mapping(address => voter) public voterInfo;
  mapping(bytes32 => uint) public votesReceived;

  constructor(uint _totalTokens, uint _tokenPrice, bytes32[] 
    _candidateNames) public {
    totalTokens = _totalTokens;
    balanceTokens = _totalTokens;
    tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
    candidateList = _candidateNames;
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function transferBalance() public {
    owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

  function buy() payable public {
    uint tokensToBuy = msg.value / tokenPrice;
    require(tokensToBuy <= balanceTokens);
    voterInfo[msg.sender].voterAddress = msg.sender;
    voterInfo[msg.sender].tokensBought += tokensToBuy;
    balanceTokens -= tokensToBuy;
  }

  function voteForCandidate(bytes32 candidate, uint tokens) public {
    // Check to make sure user has enough tokens to vote
    // Increment vote count for candidate
    // Update the voter struct tokensUsedPerCandidate for this voter

    uint availableTokens = voterInfo[msg.sender].tokensBought - 
    totalTokensUsed(voterInfo[msg.sender].tokensUsedPerCandidate);

    require(tokens <= availableTokens, "You don't have enough tokens");
    votesReceived[candidate] += tokens;

    if(voterInfo[msg.sender].tokensUsedPerCandidate.length == 0) {
      for(uint i=0; i<candidateList.length; i++) {
        voterInfo[msg.sender].tokensUsedPerCandidate.push(0);
      }
    }

    uint index = indexOfCandidate(candidate);
    voterInfo[msg.sender].tokensUsedPerCandidate[index] += tokens;
  }

  function indexOfCandidate(bytes32 candidate) view public returns(uint) 
  {
    for(uint i=0; i<candidateList.length; i++) {
      if (candidateList[i] == candidate) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return uint(-1);
  }

  function totalTokensUsed(uint[] _tokensUsedPerCandidate) private pure 
  returns (uint) {
    uint totalUsedTokens = 0;
    for(uint i=0; i<_tokensUsedPerCandidate.length; i++) {
      totalUsedTokens += _tokensUsedPerCandidate[i];
    }
    return totalUsedTokens;
  }

  function voterDetails(address user) view public returns (uint, uint[]) 
  {
    return (voterInfo[user].tokensBought, 
      voterInfo[user].tokensUsedPerCandidate);
  }

  function tokensSold() public view returns (uint) {
    return totalTokens - balanceTokens;
  }

  function allCandidates() public view returns (bytes32[]) {
    return candidateList;
  }

  function totalVotesFor(bytes32 candidate) public view returns (uint) {
    return votesReceived[candidate];
  }
}
```

The contract is deployed on ropsten testnet, voteForCandidate fails during contract execution.

Answer (score 1):

The warnings are because you have a variable-length array that you're returning or looping over. (For `transferBalance`, it's just because you're calling `transfer`, and there's no way for the compiler to know how much gas the recipient will use in their fallback function.)

You could make `indexOfCandidate` constant time by using a `mapping`. Otherwise, as long as you know there's some reasonable upper bound on the length of `candidateList`, you can ignore these warnings.

As to why `voteForCandidate` is failing, we'd need a lot more information to debug (like what the state of the contract is, what parameters you passed, etc.).